# partial unique index using foreign table

Tags: postgresql, indexing, unique

I have the following table

```sql
create type status as enum ('ACTIVE', 'NOT_ACTIVE');

create table test (
  id uuid not null default gen_random_uuid(),
  name character varying (255) not null,
  stat status not null default 'ACTIVE'::status,
  next_id uuid,
  primary key (id),
  foreign key (next_id) references test(id)
);

create table details (
  id uuid not null default gen_random_uuid(),
  test_id uuid not null,
  cid bytea not null,
  primary key (id),
  foreign key (test_id) references test(id)
);
```

my goal is to impose a partial unique index (constraint) on field `cid` from table `details` provided that field `stat` from table `test` is equal to `ACTIVE`. as far as I know, the options for enforcing partial constraints in postgres are `unique index` or `exclude constraint`. However, my problem in is that the `stat` field is located in another table.

the solution I see is to duplicate the `stat` field in the `details` table

```sql
create table details (
  id uuid not null default gen_random_uuid(),
  test_id uuid not null,
  cid bytea not null,
  stat status not null,
  primary key (id),
  foreign key (test_id) references test(id)
);

create unique index on details(cid) where (stat = 'ACTIVE');
```

and through `before insert` and `after update` triggers to synchronize it.

from here I have several questions:
Is there another option for achieving the goal?
Is there an option to avoid using triggers to synchronize the value of the `stat` field?

Comment: I don't think that there is a better solution than triggers. Uniqueness on a `bytea` is strange; if it is a bigger value, impose uniqueness on a has instead.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, cid is rfid identifier. according to the standard that will be used for reading, it will vary from 4 to 8 bytes